# Similarity Classes of 2x2 Matrices of Order n with Integer Entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am studying for a linear algebra exam and have come across a question that states:

For each $n \ge 1$ find the number of similarity classes of 2 x 2 matrices with integer entries of order exactly $n$ -  ie matrices such that $A^n = I$ but $A^k \not = I$ for any $k < n$ with integer entries.

By similarity classes, I think the question means conjugacy classes since matrices are similar if there exists $P$ such that $B = PAP^{-1}$

I am completely stuck on how to start this problem.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which level you're on there's different approaches.

**If you know complex matrices and the matrices are supposed to be complex matices**

Then you can observe that the eigenvalues for the matrix has to satisfy the same equation, that is $\lambda^k = 1$ first when $k=n$.

**If it's real matrices**

You have to show that a matrix $A$ is either:

1. a (possibly non-uniform) scaling. That is that $Ax = \lambda_u u\cdot x u + \lambda_v v\cdot x v$ for some (eigen)vectors $u$ and $v$ and (eigen)values $\lambda_u$ and $\lambda_v$
2. a scaled rotation. That is $A = cR$ for some rotation matrix $R$

After that you could show that case one is only possible if $A = I$ (for $n=1$) and $A=-I$ (for $n=2$), but that would make it fit the second type anyway.

The second type is only possible if $c=1$ and $R$ is a rotation of angle $2r\pi/n$, (the case $c=-1$ is also possible, but that would be covered by modifying the rotation by the angle $\pi$).